# Для чего нужен Caching of signature providers при валидации токена

Tags: c#, jwt, аутентификация

Всем привет и с наступающим новым годом!

У меня вопрос такой. При настройки валидации токена, с помощью библитеки `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens`, я могу указать в параметрах или глобально отключение Caching of signature providers.

```
// Глобально
CryptoProviderFactory.Default.CacheSignatureProviders = false;

// В параметрах
var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    CryptoProviderFactory = new CryptoProviderFactory()
    {
        CacheSignatureProviders = false
    }
};
```

Так как в версии библиотеки `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` 5.5.0 есть проблемы с утечкой памяти в этом месте, то я хочу отключить этот кеш. Я знаю, что если перейти на версю 6.5.0 и выше, то утечка пропадет, но мне интересен этот способ.

На что вообще влияет этот кеш и для чего он нужен? Я с ним сталкиваюсь впервые. Если это кеш, то его отключение повлечет за собой снижение производительности при валидации токена или нет?

Я пытался найти ответ в интернете но видимо плохо искал.